# React Canvas images not XORing properly

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm trying to XOR two images (foreground and background image) together, the end goal is to have a infintely looping background like [this logo](https://1.1.1.1/).

After trial and error, it seems that my foreground image is wrong because [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZsxQ.png) is the result I get after XORing my foreground as the source, and background as the destination on my canvas.

However, if I use 1.1.1.1's foreground/source on my background, it [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jx7s.png).

[Album of the background and foreground images in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAPuf.jpg)

Not sure what is wrong with my foreground/src image, or if I did something else incorrectly.

Code:

```
class LogoCanvas extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const dstImg = new Image();
        dstImg.src = background;

        const srcImg = new Image();
        srcImg.src = foreground;
        let x, width, height;

        srcImg.onload = function() {
            x = this.width / 2;
            width = this.width;
            height = this.height;

            this.requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        };


        const loop = () => {
            // drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
            // dx = x from top-left; dy = y from top-left
            // dWidth = width of image; dHeight = height of image
            ctx.drawImage(dstImg, - x % width, 0,width, height);
            ctx.drawImage(dstImg, width - x % width, 0, width, height);
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
            ctx.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, width, height);
            x++;
            this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        };

        this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(loop)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId)
    }

    render() {
        const pixelsWidth = this.props.pixelsWidth;
        const pixelsHeight = this.props.pixelsHeight;
        return (
        <div className="logo" data-aos="fade-in">
            <canvas id="canvas" ref={this.canvasRef} width={pixelsWidth ? pixelsWidth : 1000 } height={pixelsHeight ? pixelsHeight : 1000 }/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LogoCanvas;
```

Comment: XOR flips destination alpha if both (src and dest) are on else writes like "source-atop". Better to use "source-atop" Draw your logo (text, "1.1.1.1", whatever) first on a cleared canvas so it shows the page (canvas container's background). The logo should be transparent where you don't want the background effect to show. Then draw the FX image over the logo using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop"` and let the browser composite the result with the background

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the tip - fortunately I figured it out yesterday (code has been updated above). I was wondering if it was possible to draw the background image on the frontend itself as a linear-gradient instead of using a ready made image? This would allow me to easily change the colors of the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Use composite operation "source-atop" rather than XOR

Example shows this in action, the moving image is drawn twice so that it can scroll endlessly, which if you use XOR to get a similar FX will produce an ugly seam if you do not align perfectly to pixels.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekPrB.png";
img.addEventListener("load", animate, {once: "true"});
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "120px Arial Black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
function animate(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,200);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillText("1.2.3.", 250, 100);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    const x = -time / 30;
    ctx.drawImage(img,x % img.width, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img,x % img.width + img.width, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="180"></canvas>
```